# Reference about eigenvalue of Laplace operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, reference-works

My teacher tell me  that the eigenvalue question
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& -\Delta u=\lambda u   ~~~x\in \Omega   \\
& ~~~ u=0  ~~~~~~~~~~~x\in\partial\Omega
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
 has been resolved . All eigenvalue such that $0<\lambda_1<\lambda_2... $ and $\lambda_k \sim C_n(\frac{k}{|\Omega|})^{2/n}$, and $\lambda_1(\Omega)\ge\lambda_1(B) \text{ when }~|\Omega|=|B|$ and  $B$ is ball. And ......
(Sorry, I know it's very inaccurate).

I want to know which paper contains above content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/eigenvalues.pdf) contains the derivation of some basic facts. The growth of the $\lambda$ to $\infty$ is shown, and if you look closely at the proof you also get an estimate, but not as good as you have asked for I think.

On [this page](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dirichlet_eigenvalue) you'll find references to more special results, including the growth estimate you've asked about.